# How to pass parameters toolbar bar button selector method

Tags: ios, swift

I am developing an ios application using swift and storyboard. I need to pass parameters inside the toolbar bar button selector method. my objc selector method like

```
@objc func FetchDate(inputField:UITextField)
{
inputField.resignFirstResponder()
}
```

I am setting toolbar bar button item and calling the selector item like this:

```
let toolbar = UIToolbar()
toolbar.sizeToFit()

let doneBtn = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: .done, target: nil, action: #selector(AppointmentConfig.FetchDate(inputField:)))
toolbar.setItems([doneBtn], animated: true)
```

But app crashed when I pass the parameter above this. how to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Action methods only accept the sender (the UIBarButton in your case) or the sender and a UIEvent, see here https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uicontrol
So you'll the object that implements the action method will have to "know" about the UITextField you want to access... it can then forward the message to the appropriate object with the reference to the textfield as a parameter. PS generally accepted style is that method names should start with a lower case like methodName.

Comment: Any implementation code? I am new to ios I did not understand theoretically